# How do I check whether an imgur URL is a gif or an image?

Tags: python, gif, imgur

Say I have an imgur url like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nREgA.jpg

From the url I have no idea if this is a picture or a gif. I know I can add ".jpg" to the end of the file to get a direct link to the image but this will bring up the gif as well if the link happens to be a gif. How would I programmatically (using the imgur API or otherwise) check if the item at the url https://i.stack.imgur.com/nREgA.jpg or https://i.stack.imgur.com/nREgA.jpg.jpg is an image or a gif?

edit: 
I tried this

```
print(requests.head(submission.url + ".jpg").headers['Content-Type'])
```

but it complained with the following error:

```
KeyError: 'content-type'
```

implying content-type was not a key in the header. I printed the headers and confirmed this as they are the following:

```
{'Content-Length': '0', 'X-Served-By': 'cache-sjc3138-SJC', 'X-Cache': 'HIT', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'X-Timer': 'S1498627080.598287,VS0,VE0', 'Server': 'cat factory 1.0', 'Retry-After': '0', 'Connection': 'close', 'X-Cache-Hits': '0', 'Location': 'https://i.imgur.com/APMnK9t.jpg', 'Cache-Control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', 'Date': 'Wed, 28 Jun 2017 05:17:59 GMT', 'X-Frame-Options': 'DENY'}
```

I suppose I could check if content-length is not 0 to see if it is a gif? Thoughts?

Comment: but a gif *is* an image...

Comment: What's the value of `submission.url`?

Comment: http://imgur.com/vU95acN, https://imgur.com/APMnK9t are examples of the urls that are in the submission.url field - someone suggested adding an i to the front of them so i will try that

Comment: "Someone" being me? :-)

Comment: yes that someone was @smarx haha thanks for the help man

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [`requests` library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/):

```
import requests

def get_content_type(url):
    return requests.head(url).headers['Content-Type']

print(get_content_type('https://i.imgur.com/pCEoGjF.jpg'))  # image/jpeg
print(get_content_type('https://i.imgur.com/kJNdeQv.jpg'))  # image/gif
```

Comment: thanks but this gives a KeyError: 'content-type' error. thoughts?

Comment: Can you share your code? The code here runs fine for me.

Comment: sure but it seems the issue is the headers do not have a content-type key. i printed out the headers and they are the following: {'Content-Length': '0', 'X-Served-By': 'cache-sjc3138-SJC', 'X-Cache': 'HIT', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'X-Timer': 'S1498627080.598287,VS0,VE0', 'Server': 'cat factory 1.0', 'Retry-After': '0', 'Connection': 'close', 'X-Cache-Hits': '0', 'Location': 'https://i.imgur.com/APMnK9t.jpg', 'Cache-Control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', 'Date': 'Wed, 28 Jun 2017 05:17:59 GMT', 'X-Frame-Options': 'DENY'}

Comment: The presence of a `Location` header makes me think this is a redirect response. Without seeing your code, it's hard to be sure.

Comment: My best guess... you're missing the `i.` at the beginning of the URL. You can either add it or use `allow_redirects=True` in the `requests.head` call.

Comment: (The second option is slower... it will take two round trips to imgur instead of one.)

Comment: you're right - your code works great but for some reason mine is not :/ thanks for the help. In my code i am loading the imgur url from reddit and it seems to be introducing a bug